# How can we have a single resource file which contains URLs or constant members and we use them all over the application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In **iPhone** , I just want to **store all URL at global level** so that I should be able to access those by some id or something . I found out one way like implementing a **category** for NSObject so that we can access those members everywhere as all the classes are subclassed from **NSObject** . But I don't like this way . 
          Is there a simple and smarter way to do this. This is gonna save a lot of time each time I want to change the value of any of the URL .

Thank you all in advance !!

Comment: Do you want them stored in code or in an external file? I'd suggest a custom plist file containing all your URLs and then a static wrapper class that exposes them.

Comment: @tomasmcguinness : oh yes , that can be done with the plist . But I am not sure , I mean I need to test the application where all urls are modified for the server . So each time I want to test I need to change the url with the new server name. I see but can you please explain about the wrapper class , any hint on that . . . Thanks

Comment: Create a property that can be set at run-time via preferences for the root URL segment. Use a plist to store all the relative parts and then concat on load or change to the root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include all your url into a separate header file (*.h) that you can import into all classes which needs them.
There you can write a static constant or a preprocessor #define statement

```
static NSString * const kSampleURL = @"http://stackoverflow.com";
```

or

`#define kSampleURL @"http://stackoverflow.com"`

Answer (score 0):

Its better you code-in all your constant attributes in some file named "Constants.h". Strings can be written down as:

```
static const NSString *kURL = @"www.google.com";
```

And include this `Constants.h` file in the `pch` file so that your constants are available throughout the project.

Comment: I will try including this file in .pch , great idea . Thanks!!